# How can I prevent vscode modifying newlines at the end of files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, newline

Whenever I save files with vscode, a newline is being added or removed (I can't tell from looking at the diff) in every file.

I don't care whether files have newlines at the end or not, so this is commit noise I have to reject every time I make a change.

**How can I stop vscode from modifying newlines at ends of files?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open the Settings Editor and search for *newline*. Change the `files.insertFinalNewline` setting.

[image: Screenshot of settings editor]

Comment: Thanks! Oddly though `files.trimFinalNewlines` and `files.insertFinalNewline` aren't set - and their default is `false` - but VSCode still seems to be adding/removing newlines.